# Creating a JSON structure in PDI without blocks

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pdi

I'm trying to get a simple JSON output value in PDI from a field that was defined in an earlier step. 
The field is `id_trans`, and I want the result to look like `{"id_trans":"1A"}` when `id_trans` value is `1A`.

However, when using the JSON Output step and setting the json bloc name to empty, I get this: `{"":[{"id_trans":"1A"}]}`, which is normal given that the JSON Ouptut step generates json blocks, as specified in the doc.

How can I get rid of the bloc ( i.e. `[]`) structure in a simple manner? I thought of using an external python script, but I would rather use steps in PDI.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that with another `JSON Input step`. Just specify your output value from JSON Output step as `Select field` and under the tab fields, specify a fieldname and `data[0]` as Path.